# audio decompression using ffmpeg doesn't increase the file size

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a compressed audio file (REC00008.wav) with a size of 28519 KB.

I decompressed it to a new file (uncompressed_REC00008.wav).

I used the code below. There is no error from FFmpeg but the size of both of these files is the same. After decompressing, I believe the file size should normally increase a little.

```
ffmpeg -i E:\\vishnu\\LargeSizedAudios\\REC00008.wav -f wav -ab 192000 -vn C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\AudioDecompressOut\\uncompressed_REC00008.wav
```

Here is the command line output of the above written code:

```
E:\vishnu>ffmpeg -i E:\\vishnu\\LargeSizedAudios\\REC00008.wav -f wav -ab 192000
 -vn C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\AudioDecompressOut\\uncompressed_REC00008.wav
ffmpeg version N-59036-g5d8e4f6 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 12 2013 22:01:01 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 58.100 / 52. 58.100
  libavcodec     55. 45.101 / 55. 45.101
  libavformat    55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     3. 92.100 /  3. 92.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'E:\\vishnu\\LargeSizedAudios\\REC00008.wav':
  Duration: 00:02:32.10, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1536 kb/s
Output #0, wav, to 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\AudioDecompressOut\\uncompressed_
REC00008.wav':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.22.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16
, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> pcm_s16le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   28518kB time=00:02:32.09 bitrate=1536.0kbits/s
video:0kB audio:28518kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000274%

E:\vishnu>
```

Comment: `pcm` is not a compressed format, so decompressing it results in the same data.

Comment: Will this code work if i try to decompress an adpcm wav file to pcm wav file.

Comment: `adpcm` is an encoding technique using logarithmic tables to map 8bit samples more effectively than the way `pcm` does.  So if you converted `adpcm` to straight `pcm`, the filesize would increase.  What is it you are trying to achieve - perhaps you could [edit] and provide more details?